# Reinitialization of dataclass object does not reinitialize nested dataclass objects

Tags: python, nested, initialization, reinitialization

I'm having trouble reinitializing nested dataclass object.

I have 2 nested dataclasses set up like so:

```
from dataclasses import dataclass, field
from typing import Dict

@dataclass
class MyNestedClass():
    field1: str = ""
    field2: int = 0
    field3: Dict[str, float] = field(default_factory=dict)

@dataclass
class MyClass():
    field1: str = ""
    field2: int = 0
    field3: Dict[str, float] = field(default_factory=dict)
    field4: MyNestedClass = MyNestedClass()
```

As part of a unit testing procedure, I would like to initialize a new `MyClass` object and then run a test.  However, I've noticed something odd.  When I reinitialize my `MyClass` object, it somehow remembers the contents of field4.  For example:

```
my_obj = MyClass()
print(my_obj)

my_obj.field2 = 1
my_obj.field3 = {'something': 2.5}
my_obj.field4.field1 = "B"
my_obj.field4.field2 = 2
my_obj.field4.field3 = {'something else': 3.14}
print(my_obj)

my_obj = MyClass()
print(my_obj)
```

yields

```
MyClass(field1='', field2=0, field3={}, field4=MyNestedClass(field1='', field2=0, field3={}))
MyClass(field1='', field2=1, field3={'something': 2.5}, field4=MyNestedClass(field1='B', field2=2, field3={'something else': 3.14}))
MyClass(field1='', field2=0, field3={}, field4=MyNestedClass(field1='B', field2=2, field3={'something else': 3.14}))
```

does the autogenerated dataclass constructor for `MyClass` not call the constructor for `MyNestedClass` by default?  If not, what is it doing instead and what is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `field4: MyNestedClass = MyNestedClass()` is essentially a [mutable default argument](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) and causes the same bugs. `MyNestedClass` is initialized once and persists, this is why it "remembers" `field4` but not `field3`. @John's solution results in a new instance of  `MyNestedClass` each time a new instance of `MyClass` is created.

Comment: You can verify that `field4` is the same instance of `MyNestedClass` with `id(my_obj.field4)`. It should be the same for every instance of `MyClass` in your question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, @MichaelRuth!  I added it to the answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Michael](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4583620/michael-ruth) points out, the constructor generated by the `@dataclass` decorator includes a [mutable default argument](https://docs.python-guide.org/writing/gotchas/#mutable-default-arguments) so that an instance of `MyNestedClass` is created only once when the `MyClass` is defined and not uniquely for each instantiation.

Defining `MyClass` using a field resolves this problem:

```
@dataclass
class MyClass():
    field1: str = ""
    field2: int = 0
    field3: Dict[str, float] = field(default_factory=dict)
    field4: MyNestedClass = field(default_factory=MyNestedClass)
```